# Update device token in installation table in parse ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios9

I want to update device token in installation table on parse using `iOS`.
To save a device token I did:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:(NSData*)[AppHelper userDefaultsForKey:@"token"]];
[currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"user"];
NSArray *channels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AnyString",nil];
currentInstallation.channels=channels;
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

I want to update this device token. I know to update token I have to use rest API i.e. https://api.parse.com/1/installations. How to update the row as I also don't have installation id.

Please provide proper syntax.

Comment: where this code has you written ?

Comment: At login time. In login view

Comment: if i delete application from my device and install it again then app will generate a new device token thats why it is necessary to update installation table in parse.

Answer (score 1):

Write below code in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method in AppDelegate .

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    PFInstallation *currnentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currnentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currnentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

For Register user in channels use below code in Login Screen

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
if ([PFUser currentUser].objectId)
{
    currentInstallation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];

    currentInstallation.channels = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_%@",[PFUser currentUser].objectId]];
    NSLog(@"Saving Installation channel = %@",currentInstallation.channels);

    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
    {
           NSLog(@"Current installation updated: Error: %@",error);
    }];
}
```

For more details , refer this link https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-installations

Comment: But i have to save userId also i.e. User objectId. As i am sending push notification using User objectId.Like this- PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
            [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" containedIn:objectIds];
            PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
            [push setQuery:pushQuery];
            [push setData:pushData];
            [push sendPushInBackground];

Comment: see updated answer to save userId in Installation tbl.

Comment: Thats great . Thanks man (Y).  You saved my time. Otherwise i was thinking to do all these with rest api i.e first to fetch whole list then delete old row and add new. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if helpful then please approve and upvote it as answer. So other users can find it as helpful.

Comment: i tried this code. With this a new entry for that device token is created. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, this method is called every time, when i run the app after deleting old build and installing new one again on device then new device token will generate and so new entry in insatllation table. I want userid as a unique key.

Comment: simply check in insatllation table that userId is exist or not. if exist then only update deviceToken in that record otherwise add new record .Write that code in AppDelegate's didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method.   And plz see parse docs or link give in answer for how to update record.

Comment: I Did this to fetch record ->NSURLRequest *parseRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/installations}]]; [parseRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; [parseRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"]; [parseRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];[parseRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"]; [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:parseRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError{}];

Comment: But in above i am getting error "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x15cea9fe0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}}}"

Comment: you use rest API? Do the code from client/App site.

Comment: to fetch installation object we have to use rest api. With PFQuery we cant fetch installation objects.and same for upation and deletion we have to use rest api for installation table.

Comment: well & good if u want to implement this using REST API . But unfortunately i don't know for how to do this type of functionality using REST API. you can visit to parse docs for more help.

Comment: Ohh.. ok no issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: see this links for how to update installation object using REST API. https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-uploading-installation-data

Comment: Ya i checked this link also. I did same as they told but still getting url issue. Moreover they didn't give code or example in objective c. They just gave in cURL and  python. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In `AppDelegate's` `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method, set deviceToken to installation table and save device token to `NSUserDefaults` ,like this:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
```

And on login or signup ,set user like this :

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"User"];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"deviceToken"]];
currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

**UPDATE:**

you need to make additions to installation table. Add column `userID` to installation and then get query installation table with current user's `userID`.
You can refer this https://www.parse.com/questions/retrieve-objectid-from-installation-table link for better understanding
Hope it helps :)

Comment: This will also create a new entry :(. I want to update the existing one. If a installation id and device token exist for that user i want to update that row. If not exit then create a new row.

Comment: you are using deviceToken for push notification. Above code is working in my app without any issue. Anyways , I've updated my answer

Comment: It also working fine on my side. Problem occurs when there are multiple entries for same user with different device token in installation table.

Comment: then updated answer can help you... Did yo try that ?

Comment: Yeah, i m doing in same way. And to fetch installation id i have to use rest api.And updation also requires rest api.