# Am I using the installation class correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to send notifications to selected users. When the send button is clicked, the program will send the notification to the selected users. This is my first time with notifications and I don't know if I am doing this correctly. If someone can help me that would be great! :) 
Below is my attempt at this. 
[image]

```
var setOfSelectedFriends = Set<String>()

func send(sender: UIButton){
    pushNotifications()
}

func pushNotifications(){
    let message = "Alert!"
    let data = ["title": "Some Title", "alert": message]
    var userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    userQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: setOfSelectedFriends)

    let query: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
    query.whereKey("username", matchesQuery: userQuery)

    var push: PFPush = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(query)
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPushInBackground()
}
```

This is in my appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}
```

Comment: but there is no data in your Installation table, have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053592/update-device-token-in-installation-table-in-parse-ios and for more info : https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications

Comment: I don't think you can apply a set to `whereKey:equalTo:` - You will need to use `query.whereKey("username",containedIn:Array(setOfSelectedFriends)`

Comment: @raki I updated my code with adding data, but it still does not add any data to the installation class.

Comment: save the installation object with completion block, then you will have a chance to know if there is any error....you can save as  installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Error is %@",error.description) }];